# MySQL: show how many columns in an composite index are used

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

Using `explain` in MySQL can tell me if an composite index is used or not. But there's no clue if all columns of the composite index are used.
To aid my index design, I need to know exactly how many leftmost columns are in effect. How can I know this extra information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *key_len* field of the EXPLAIN output shows the size of the index which MySQL plans to use (the name of which is shown in *key* field). See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html.

If the index is composite, *key_len* effectively shows how many columns of the *key* index are used. For example, if *key* is an index on two not-nullable 32-bit integer columns, *key_len* can be 4 if only the first part of the index is used (only the first column) or 8 if the whole index is used.

Comment: You're right! Thanks! But notice a nullable int column takes up 5 bytes instead of 4.

Comment: This answer works for the `WHERE` clause.  But not if the optimizer can move on into the `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY`.  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` gives more info, and comes close to being "yes".

Answer (score 0):

> **No.**

[Please read the following document. It has a thorough explanation of what EXPLAIN can do and what it can't.](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/)